# What is the most effective way to farm AP?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Now that I've unlocked most of the Ascension skills that cost less than 100 AP, I've got a lot of 333 and 999 cost Ascension skills left to unlock, including skills that would remove the Damage Limit on techniques and link attacks that I want very much.

That said, I don't think I've ever had 999 or even 333 AP saved up at any given time in my 70 hours of playtime. What's the best way to rack up a ton of AP in a timely fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I have found to farm AP is after chapter 4, once you have the **Beast Whistle**, you go to the west of Hammerhead, at the Three Valleys.

You have to go during the day and "summon beasts". These enemies can be killed in one hit by using warp strikes and you'll receive 1 AP for each one you've defeated.

**[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5gmf8m/found_the_perfect_place_if_you_want_to_farm_ap/)**

Comment: How often can I use the beast whistle? This is a good answer, though. I had been getting AP by fighting the group of Magitek officers (+2 mechs) outside of the catacombs where Jormungand is located (they're level 3 and didn't always die in a single hit, so not as good as your suggestion).

Comment: Once you have killed all the beasts, you can use the whistle again inmediately. It is very handy for this purpose.

Comment: I would add a small item to this answer, using the Shield of the Just makes this farm easier. It may work on your other option too @Vemonus, but Im not sure how quickly you can respawn that group of officers. The shield does an aoe attack on a warp strike. So you can kill all of the dogs in one attack.

Comment: @Mayshar that is a really good suggestion. An AOE would be great for the officers group I mentioned, since they start in a tight formation. I am actually currently working on getting the rest of the Royal Arms and that one will definitely be the next one I get after I finish getting the Mace from the volcano area.

Comment: Do you get the AP for killing stuff in one hit with warp strike or is it for killing this particular beast and that happens to be a fast way to kill them?

Comment: @Kat You always get 1 AP for a warp strike kill, although I believe there is an ascension node you must unlock first.